# Selenium fails to start Chromedriver - Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ubuntu

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

It never actually reaches this and fails with:

```
root@server:~# python /root/EmailBot/main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/EmailBot/main.py", line 22, in <module>
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
        desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
        self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64)
```

of importance:

```
root@server:~# which chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver

root@server:~# ll /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8950080 Oct  3 14:09 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver*

root@server:~# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94
```

I have tried EVERY thread I can find and no solutions are working. I'm not sure if this is because it is a python 3.6 problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try giving the chrome webdriver path directly inside the parenthesis?
Same code works perfectly on my windows machine.
I have set environment variables, else i need to provide the path directly.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for your commitment to answering. I disregarded this since it wasn't getting any attention and found a workaround solution. Thanks again.